# Rails 3.2.13 and strong_parameters exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, strong-parameters

I'm playing around with Rails 3.2.13 and the strong_parameters gem. I wanted to know if I should be getting a raised exception from `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes` when I'm testing in development?

My Post model has a `:title` and `:content` but if I remove `:title` from permit, I don't get an error but I do get redirected back to the edit page with the flash notice, so it's saved the record. Although, it didn't change the `:title`, rightfully so. Is this the default behaviour?

```
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content)
  end
```

I wanted to know if I need to do something else to get the raised exception.

Gemfile:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem "strong_parameters"
```

Application config:

```
# config/application.rb
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

Post model:

```
# post.rb model
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection
end
```

Post Controller:

```
# post_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
       redirect_to edit_post_path(@post), flash { success: "Post updated" }
     else
       render "edit"
     end
  end


  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default configuration is to log the exception in development and test environments, and not even that in production. So what you are seeing is the normal behaviour, the assignment fails silenty.

To raise an exception you need to change the default in your desired enviroment.
For instance, config/environments/development.rb:

```
# Raises an error on unpermitted attributes assignment
  config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise  # default is :log
```

Hope that helps,